# react-select how to get a selected option

Tags: react-select

I am using react-select package in my project.I am able to show the options in the drop down make it searchable and create a new options.My issue is with how to get the select option again ie, the one i have chosen or saved from the options when i reopen the select option again.

my select component is mounted as,

```
                <CreatableSelect
                  onChange={""}
                  defaultValue={desigValues}
                  options={selectSearchOptionsDesignation}
                  styles={customStyles}
                  isSearchable
                  placeholder="Designation"
                  />
```

here selectSearchOptionsDesignation is an array and desigValues has the value which i have selected from the menu